# Link to View page in TPL file?

Tags: theming

Is it possible in a TPL to create a link to a View page? Rather than hard code the link I would like it to update if the URL of the view page changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Page display name of the view is `page`, then it prints the path

```
$view = views_get_view($view_name, TRUE);      
print $view->display['page']->display_options['path'];
```

Comment: Is $view_name the machine name of the View? Do I keep the $ at the beginning?

Comment: No it is just the name, for example if the it is `library` then use views_get_view("library", TRUE);

Comment: Ah I missed off the "".

Answer (score 0):

Use [views_get_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7) to get **$view** object.

Using view object you can find view path. It expects view name, which would obviously remain intact in your case.